# Mocking IOC container for Laravel package test

Tags: laravel, testing, binding, request, inversion-of-control

I'm working on a package that interacts with the current request to retrieve information. To retrieve that information, I use `$request = Container::getInstance()->make('request');`.

It works perfect when I use it in a Laravel application. However, I'm trying to get full code coverage in my tests. I believe I need to create a new Container object and pass it a request for my test, but it's not working out so great. Here's what I'm doing...

```
/**
 * Create a mock request
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Http\Request
 */
public function createDummyRequest($headers = [], $payload = null): Request
{
    return new Request([], [], [], [], [], $headers, $payload);
}

/**
 * Create a dummy IOC container
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Container\Container
 */
public function createDummyContainer(): Container
{
    return new Container;
}

/** @test */
public function response_preferred_format_returns_xml()
{
    $container = $this->createDummyContainer();

    $request = $this->createDummyRequest(['Accept' => 'application/json'], json_encode($this->testArray));

    $container->instance('request', $request);

    $response = $this->createDummyResponse()->preferredFormat($this->testArray, 200, ['Accept' => 'application/xml']);

    $this->assertEquals($this->testXml, $response->getContent());
}
```

The error I get is:

```
ReflectionException: Class request does not exist
```

Am I on the right track, or am I missing something obvious? Why can't I instantiate the `Container` class and bind an instance of `Request` so my code can utilize it?

Comment: Nothing in your testing code is going to touch Container::getInstance().  You're creating a dummy container instance but what exactly are you doing with that instance after it's created?

Comment: Well, in the test, I was trying to create an instance of Container and bind Request to it to simulate a request. Then the method ``preferredFormat`` basically reads the Request's Accept header and determines if it should parse the response as XML or JSON.

Comment: Right, but you don't do anything with your dummy container, so how is your code supposed to retrieve it?  Why use a dummy container?